# How to update express/lib/application.js to match different app.js file?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

MEAN noob here. I was following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/routing-views-with-angular), but `npm start` gives me the following error:

> `Error: Cannot find module './view'`...
>
> `at Object.<anonymous> (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:22:12)`

This is what `application.js` says at that location:

```
var query = require('./middleware/query');
var debug = require('debug')('express:application');
var View = require('./view'); /////// line 22
```

I have a `lib/middleware` but not a `lib/view`, nor `lib/util`...

My theory is perhaps I screwed the express installation up: It's possible I didn't have the correct app.js in place when I installed it. Does app.js affect express's installation?

**Is there a way to rebuild express or `express/lib` without uninstalling & reinstalling everything?**

**Would this even fix my problem?**

Comment: Nope. Generally, you could remove node_modules/ folder, then type `npm install` again. node_modules/ is a folder for installed library defined in package.json.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was able to fix it by re-reading through one of those tutorial chapters. I realized I created a new folder via `npm install -g express-generator`, but subsequent commands were given via the parent folder. I deleted everything and started over. Thanks.